# How could I simplify this algebra expresion?

Tags: complex-numbers, arithmetic

I had been solving an equation with complex numbers: $z = \frac{x - iy}{x + iy}$ I solved it up to the point where I get: $z = \frac{x^{2} - y^{2}}{x^{2} + y^{2}}$. But I have no idea how to simplify it! Could anyone help me? I would be glad to learn how to simplify $\frac{x^{2} + y^{2}}{x^{2} - y^{2}}$ as well...

Comment: I think once you get to your result, the only think I can think of is solving for either $x$ or $y$, and then you can have infinitely many solutions by choosing an $x$ and solving for $y$

Comment: multiply numerator and denominator by $x-iy$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$z=\frac{x-iy}{x+iy}=\frac{(x-iy)^2}{(x+iy)(x-iy)}\\=\frac{x^2-y^2-2ixy}{x^2+y^2}$$
So the real part is your answer $\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$, but it also has an imaginary part: $\frac{-2xy}{x^2+y^2}$.
It doesn't get simpler than that; but at least the real and imaginary parts are untangled.